# present, past, past participle form of 'spit'

Tags: word-usage, meaning, past-participles

I saw this sentence on the internet.

i know being spit on is probably not what you need right now

In this sentence, spit is past participle form of verb, spit.
I know past form of spit is spit, spitted, spat and past participle is spit, spatted, spat
Is this right?
Why should I use spit in stead of spatted, spat?

Answer (score 1):

Colins Dictionary [says](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spit#:%7E:text=Word%20forms%3A%20plural%2C%203rd%20person,past%20tense%20and%20past%20participle.&text=Spit%20is%20the%20watery%20liquid%20produced%20in%20your%20mouth.)

> **spit**
>
> past tense, past participle *spat*
>
> **In American English, the form *spit* is used as the past tense and past participle.**

So both *spit* and *spat* are fine in your sentence.

> I know being spit/spat on is probably not what you need right now.

Answer (score 0):

I spit.

Yesterday I spat.

In the past week, I have spat.

"I spitted (something)" means that "I passed a long metal rod with a crank at the end through the centre of a piece of meat, so as to roast it over a fire by winding the crank."

That is, "to spit" (transitive) means "to mount on a spit", and its past tense is "spitted".

So "spitted" and "spat" are completely different words, from a completely different usage of the word "spit".

There is no such word as "spatted" (at least in this context).

A "spat" (noun) is a "trivial fight between cats, little girls and celebrity wives". Hence "spatted" could possibly mean "had a spat", but I've never seen that.

And to answer your question, "I have spat" is better than "I have spit", although it is *possible* that "I have spit" is correct. Hence I would say "I have been spat on" rather than "I have been spit on".

Comment: just a small one: "in the past week" mans past so present perfect "I have spat" is not grammatically correct.

Comment: @Brandon - past present perfect "I have spat" is perfectly OK.

Comment: We can't use present perfect with an explicit "past tense implier"(according to my intellect and knowledge which have been being formed from school.

Comment: @Brandon Your English teacher may not be as clever as he thinks he is, or at least, not as clever as you think you are.

Answer (score -1):

The verb "spit"—when used to mean "throw out saliva from the mouth"—has three forms of conjugation for tense.

1. spit-spit-spit
2. spit-spitted-spitted
3. spit-spat-spat

Three of them are correct for your example sentence.

But no. 1(spit-spit-spit) is not that much used compared with no. 2 and 3.

In American English, no. 1 is often used.

For 'spat', spat is also a noun and a verb as well, which means a trivial fight or have a trivial fight. As a verb, the word 'spat's past and past participle are "spatted". So it's a totally diffrent word from the 'spit's conjugations above of no. 1, 2, and 3.

**After Edit**

The verb "spit" has 3 kinds of past and past participle as below.

1. spit-spit-spit
2. spit-spitted-spitted
3. spit-spat-spat

Both no. 1 and 3 are correct for your example sentence but 2 is wrong.
In case of No. 1 and 3 conjugation, it's when they mean "throw out saliva from the mouth"

In case of no. 2 conjugation, it's when it means "to pierce something like a meat"

For 'spat', spat is also a noun and a verb as well, which means a trivial fight or have a trivial fight. As a verb, the word 'spat's past and past participle are "spatted". So it's a totally diffrent word from the 'spit's conjugations above of no. 1, 2, and 3.

So, no. 1 and 3 are correct and no. 2 is wrong for your example sentence.
But "spit-spat-spat" is more frequently used than "spit-spit-spit"

In American English, 'spit-spit-spit' is often used(not that much used).

Comment: 2 sounds completely wrong here. "Spitted" is the past tense of the word "to spit" (transitive) where "spit" means "to spit a piece of meat for roasting on a fire". But when used as the past tense of "to spit saliva from the mouth" it sounds like the sort of thing a young child would say before being corrected by an adult. Wiktionary agrees.

Comment: Thx for advice. My bad. The original answer has now edit version after accepting your comment.