# "Right" in this phrasal verb

Tags: word-meaning, phrasal-verbs

I have a question. There is a sentence:

> I gave her a candy and she spat it right out; she said it tasted bad.

Does ***right*** in this sentence means ***immediately*** like in "I'll be right back"?

Comment: I've corrected the errors in your question ("spit" should be "spat", and "have" should be "gave".

Comment: @BillJ thank you) in the book was written "spit"

Comment: @BillJ - many sources say 'spit' is an acceptable past tense and past participle in US English.

Comment: I don't think that is a phrasal verb.  A phrasal verb is one that contains a verb and a preposition or adverb *and means something different from the combined meaning of the individual words*.  Like "throw up" - it does not mean "to throw, in an upward direction".  In this case, she is still spitting the candy; *right* and *out* just modify how she is doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is "right" being used as an adverb, and can mean a variety of things including *completely*, *immediately*, or *to a great degree*.

In your example, it should really be "**spat** it right out" ('spat' is the past participle of the verb *to spit*), but it might be that the writer wanted to convey colloquial speech. In either case, "spat/spit it *right out*" conveys the idea that they spat out the whole thing, or that they spat it out so hard it came out the mouth in a projectile fashion.

Comment: Spit is also sometimes used for the past tense and past participle, especially in North American English - Oxford Learner's Dictionaries

Comment: LANGUAGE NOTE: In American English, the form spit is used as the past tense and past participle. Collins Dictionary

Comment: [present, past, past participle form of 'spit'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/272606/present-past-past-participle-form-of-spit)